# How to detect screen resize events coming from ncurses in QNX?

Tags: terminal, ncurses, uart, qnx

I can not configure to receive events about changing the size of the terminal using ncurses QNX Momentics. 
I am using Putyy as a terminal and data is transmitted through the COM port.

My question is how to realize the reception of screen change events when using a remote terminal?

```
FILE* fcons = fopen("/dev/ser1", "r+");
SCREEN* term = newterm("xterm-r5", fcons, fcons);
int y = 0, x = 0;
//if(y < 24 || x < 80)
//  resizeterm(24, 80);
flushinp();
main_scr = newwin(24, 80, 0, 0);
head_scr = subwin(main_scr, 3, 80, 0, 0);
prompt_scr = subwin(main_scr, 1, 9, 3, 2);
cursor_scr = newwin(1, 60, 3, 6);
output_scr = subwin(main_scr, 18, 76, 5, 2);
keypad(cursor_scr, TRUE);

int f = mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS, NULL);

chtype temp_ch = 0;
while(KEY_RESIZE == temp_ch)
   temp_ch = wgetch(cursor_scr);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plain serial-port connection like that won't send a `SIGWINCH`.  In other configurations, e.g., `telnet`, that's done as a result of *NAWS* (negotiations about window size--I dont't [see a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=naws)).  Your application *could* poll for this by doing what the [`resize`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program does, plus a little more, e.g.,

- save the cursor-position
- move the cursor to a very-far-off lower-right corner
- ask the terminal where the cursor really is
- wait for the response, to get the actual screensize
- set the terminal's screensize using a system call
- restore the cursor position
- send a `SIGWINCH` to yourself

Unlike `resize`, that would be done inside your program, so it would have to save/restore the cursor position (to avoid confusing ncurses).  Keep in mind that ncurses has set the terminal to *raw mode*, so that part of the initialization would not be needed.

Comment: The oddity is that the mouse clicks work for me. But to catch the resizing of the terminal does not work. Although both events occur when using the mouse.

Comment: resize-events aren't related to the mouse (nor are they handled the same way).  ncurses asks PuTTY to send an escape sequence on mouse-events, but there's no protocol defined for sending escapes when the terminal is resized.